# Php check data and fetch result to another page

Tags: php

currently I have a PHP code called checking.php and there is two column I have on the web page which is identification number and password. what I want to achieve is once I click the submit button, the code will check whether the input is matching with the database or not, if match, it will proceed to homescreen.php and fetching some of the user data from the database table. but now I am stuck on how to fetch the data from that particular column after the checking.to make it more clear, I set an example:

database info:
name: john
passcode:1234
birthday:1/2/2011
ic:70202025

from checking.php, the user requires to type in ic and passcode to authenticate, once the info is correct, it will show its name and birthday on homescreen.php.

here is my code for checking.php:

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig/config01.php';

?>


    <form class="myform" action="BranchhavingProblem01.php" method="post">


        <label><b>Identification Card No.</b></label>
        <input name="CUS_IC" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="IC No."required/><br>
        <label><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input name="CUS_PASSWRD" type="password" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Password"required/><br>

        <input name="login" type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login"/><br>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $CUS_IC=$_POST['CUS_IC'];
            $CUS_PASSWRD=$_POST['CUS_PASSWRD'];


            $query = "select * from memberinfo WHERE CUS_IC='$CUS_IC' AND CUS_PASSWRD ='$CUS_PASSWRD' ";

            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
            {
                //valid
                $_SESSION['CUS_IC']=$CUS_IC;


                header ('location:homeScreen.php');
            }
            else
            {
                //invalid
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Invalid Credentials")</script>';
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hey, just so you are aware your code is actually vulnerable to SQL injection and is not fit for running in production. Look into how to use [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) it's quite simple to use! Infact I bet `1' or 1=1;--`  as the CUS_IC will likely bypass your login..

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but if you need data from the result set, you can use `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: Ditto. What's your question? Which part of this isn't working, and how is it not working?

Comment: As for your actual question; You can use `$_SESSIONS` for passing the data.You must run `session_start()` before doing anything with the `$_SESSION` global tho! I'm still going to urge you to use the `prepare` from MySQL so you should also give [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) a read to understand how to pull results

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I'll look into it, however, for the data fetching part do you have any idea how to achieve? Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On checking.php set a session variable which i assume you are setting it on  `$_SESSION['CUS_IC']=$CUS_IC;` and when you move to homescreen.php , first check

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CUS_IC'])) {
 $query = "select * from memberinfo WHERE CUS_IC='$_SESSION['CUS_IC']' 

}
```

Then display the desire results

Answer (score 0):

This is my checking.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbconfig/config01.php';
?>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $CARD_UID=$_POST['CARD_UID'];



            $query = "select * from memberinfo WHERE CARD_UID='$CARD_UID' ";

            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
            {
            //valid
               $_SESSION['CARD_UID']=$CARD_UID;
               $_SESSION['CUS_NAME']=$data['CUS_NAME'];
               $_SESSION['CUS_IC']=$data['CUS_IC'];

              header ('location:homeScreen.php');
            }
            else
            {
                //invalid
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Invalid Credentials")</script>';
            }
        }

    ?>
```

This is my homescreen.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Loyalty System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ECF0F1">

    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <center>
    <h2>Welcome 
    <?php echo $_SESSION['CUS_NAME']?>!
    </h2>

    <h3>Your IC is: 
    <?php echo $_SESSION['CUS_IC']?> 
    </h3>
```

Comment: I adjust the code on checking.php,but nothing shows up in my homescreen.php,can you tell me where gone wrong?

Comment: did you call your birthday and name session in `homeScreen.php`? 

its like `<?=$_SESSION[....]?>`

Comment: i did not, the code i just posted for homescreen.php is what i wrote. So, may i ask how to call out a session?

Comment: i dont now what name of field in your database, so check it plis

Comment: I did change the code but still empty on the homescreen.php,the data still isnt draw out from the database once it login

Comment: if you did right, it will show up. but if you didnt get it, there some error and try to use var_dump so you know what your problem. btw sorry for my bad language. :D

Comment: You're very kind sir for helping me, i am going to upload the code for the last time to see what went wrong

Comment: im glad to help you. and i dont see error again except this code is actually vulnerable to SQL injection.